# When custom map style is provided, @/react-google-maps/api doesn’t render map, or does with errors

Tags: react-google-maps-api

Map is working normally but when I pass mapId prop (custom google cloud map styling) it stops rendering tiles and throws error.

when I pass mapId in options

```
options = {{
   mapId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}}
```

and in LoadScript wrapper

`<LoadScript mapIds={['xxxxxxxxxx']}>`

it instantly throws error

> webgl.js:541 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')

I am not sure when this error started happening but I know I didn’t encounter it till recently, now when I go to older commits its happening there also.

I also didnt include mapIds in wrapper before but now when I don’t it throws error

> webgl.js:234 Uncaught Error: Not initialized.

Sometimes the map renders completely without issue, but most of the time no tiles are loaded, just markers (in some cases first tile is loaded, when zoomed out no more tiles are loaded. But always there is error:

> Uncaught (in promise)

I also tried removing the markers but its the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I hope this helps. Sometimes the maps component is still not loaded completely even after onload is called, so you are probably running a function on the map before it's stable. For instance, if you want to use `map.fitBounds` you can use a workaround like this where you use `tilesloaded` event to detect a completely loaded map and then you can run your function on the map.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";

function MapView({ center, zoom, markers }) {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const [fullyLoaded, setFullyLoaded] = useState(false);

    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: "google-map-script",
        googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
        mapIds: [process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_MAP_ID],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (map && isLoaded) {
            const listener = window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
                setFullyLoaded(true);
                listener.remove();
            });
        }
    }, [map, isLoaded]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (markers && fullyLoaded) {
            const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            markers.map((marker) => bounds.extend(marker.position));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }, [markers, fullyLoaded]);

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoaded && 
                <GoogleMap
                    options={{ mapId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_MAP_ID }}
                    center={center}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
                    onUnmount={() => {
                        setMap(null);
                        setFullyLoaded(false);
                    }}
                />
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```